# Assignment, about 2d arrays

Tags: c

I would like some assistance with a problem.

I have this text file:

I input the contents of the text into a string 2d array and converted it to a integer 2d array. When i converted to the int array the nan's were replaced with a zero. I now proceeded to find the max and min of each line in the 2d array and find the average of both, which I successfully achieved. My problem is I want to assign the average value found for each line to the zero. I tried using two for loops but it replacing all the zero's with the average of the first line. Can anyone please assist me.

**My code:**

```
int min = 200;

int main() {

    fstream imagefile;
    imagefile.open("Text.txt");

    if (imagefile.fail()) { // checking for errors in file
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        exit(1);

    std::string data[3][11];
    int integer[3][11];
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            imagefile >> data[k][i]; // read from file

        }
    }

    cin.get();

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            integer[k][i] = atoi(data[k][i].c_str()); // converts string to int 
        }
    }
    cin.get();

    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) { //k is the row  and i is the column

        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            cout << integer[k][i] << "  ";

        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    int row, col;
    for (row = 0; row < 3; row++) { //k is the row  and i is the column

        max = integer[row][0];
        min = integer[row][0];

        for (col = 0; col < 11; col++) {
            if (integer[row][col] > max) { max = integer[row][col]; }
            if ((integer[row][col] < min) && (integer[row][col] != 0)) { min = integer[row][col]; }
            //if (integer[row][col] == 0) { avg == integer[row][col]; }

            sum = max + min;
            avg = sum / 2;
        }
            for (int k = 0; k < integer[k][i]; k++) {  //k is the row  and i is the column
                for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
                    if (integer[k][i] == 0) {

                        integer[k][i] = avg;

                    }
                    cout << integer[k][i] << "  ";

                }
                cout << endl;
            }

        cout << max << " ";
        cout << min << " ";
        cout << avg << " " << endl;
    }

    imagefile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems two 0's in your last row, you want to assign average to both of them or just one of them ?

Comment: Minimum except 0 right ?

Comment: OK! I commented the code, It may help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the code you've presented. This line:

```
    imagefile >> data[k][i];
```

Error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and:

```
    for (int k = 0; k < integer[k][i]; k++)
```

Error C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier (78)

Try posting the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code will work perfectly if you will have this file.

> > Note: Your Text.txt should be exactly this format. Not with a blank line.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream in("Text.txt");
    char ch = '\0'; int count = 1; //Ac counter to count number of rows
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in.get(ch);
        if (ch == '\n') //counting lines
            count++;
    }
    in.close();
    double *avgArray = new double[count]; //array to store avg of min/max of every row
    int arraySize = count;
    in.open("Text.txt");
    count = 0;
    string strTemp = "";
    int temp = 0; //temp to get int values
    int sum = 0; //calculate sum of avery row
    int i = 0; //index number
    int max = 0;
    int min = 99999;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> strTemp;
        if (strTemp == "NaN")
            temp = 0;
        else
            temp = atoi(strTemp.c_str());
        if (temp > max)
            max = temp;
        if (temp < min && temp!=0)
            min = temp;
        in.get(ch);
        if (ch == '\n' || in.eof()) //if new line occured 
        {
            avgArray[i] = double(max + min) / 2.0; //store avg in abg array
            max = 0;
            min = 99999;
            i++; //counter of avg array
        }
    }
    in.close();
    //for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) //printing
        //cout << avgArray[i]<<endl; //avg of all rows
    in.open("Text.txt");
    i = 0;
    int col = 0; //counter for cols
    int SizeCol = 0;
    temp = 0;
    strTemp = "";
    double **DataArray = new double*[arraySize]; //2D array to store file data
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        in >> strTemp;
        if (strTemp == "NaN")
            temp = 0;
        else
            temp = atoi(strTemp.c_str());
        in.get(ch);
        col++; //counting columns
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            DataArray[i] = new double[col]; //making dynmically cols
            i++;
            SizeCol = col;
            col = 0;
        }
        if (in.eof())
            DataArray[i] = new double[col]; //for last line of file
    }
    in.close();
    in.open("Text.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SizeCol; j++)
        {
            in >> strTemp;
            if (strTemp == "NaN")
                temp = 0;
            else
                temp = atoi(strTemp.c_str());
            DataArray[i][j]=temp;
            if (DataArray[i][j] == 0)
                DataArray[i][j] = avgArray[i]; //Assigning avg of row at row's 0 place
        }
    }
    in.close();

    //Printing the final array
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SizeCol; j++)
        {
            cout<< DataArray[i][j]<<" "; //printing
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    ofstream out("Text.txt");
    //Wrting the final array into Text.txt
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < SizeCol; j++)
        {
            out << DataArray[i][j] << " "; //Writing
        }
        out << endl;
    }
    delete[] avgArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        delete DataArray[i];
    delete[] DataArray;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not know matlab, Ask in matlab tab.

Comment: What is the other thing ? @guestuser

Comment: Assign nan number before it? Then what to assign NaN? @guestuser